# 'CUnit/Basic.h' file not found MacOS

Tags: c, macos, homebrew

I use a MacBook and just recently installed CUnit with HomeBrew.
The installation went well (had no errors or warnings, so I guess it's alright). After that I wanted to run a test file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <CUnit/Basic.h>
int main(void) {
printf("Hello, world!\n");
return 0;
}
```

Sadly after running this line `gcc -o test test.c`, I got this error:

```
test.c:3:10: fatal error: 'CUnit/Basic.h' file not found
#include <CUnit/Basic.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Can anyone help me with that? I really don't understand how this can happen even though the installation went well (I guess).

Comment: Try adding the argument `-I/usr/local/include` to your `g++` command.

Comment: you mean like this?
`gcc -I /usr/local/include -o test test.c`

Comment: Yes, without the space in `-I` and `/usr/local/include`.

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: What is the result of the command `ls /usr/local/include`?

Comment: `dbm.h       gdbm-ndbm.h gdbm.h      lzma        lzma.h`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229060/discussion-between-llamaking136-and-luca-archidiacono).

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was, Homebrew installed the package in this path `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cunit/2.1-3/` but `gcc` looks default-wise for all the header-files inside `/usr/local/include` or `/usr/include`.

To point to the installed Homebrew package-path follow these steps:
https://web.archive.org/web/20090129230009if_/http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_23.html

You just need to configure environmental variables ;)

Comment: To make your answer even better, please add at least an extract of the linked resource. External resources might vanish.

Comment: plus one, it WILL vanish.